# Pass HTML as agrumnet within inclusion tag

Tags: html, django

I have created an inclusion tag for creating a certain number of columns within a row:

```
<tr>
    {% for col in cols %}<td>{{ col }}</td>{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

My inclusion_tag function is:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("row_with_cols.html")
def row_with_cols(*cols):
    return {"cols": cols}
```

So I can now pass as many values I want to my rows as I want with something like:

```
{% row_with_cols "Full name" session.userinfo.name %}
```

This is all well and good however to take this to the next level I would like to pass in arguments that are HTML arguments.

For example, I want to turn something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td>
        <img src="{{ session.userinfo.picture }}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

into

```
{% row_with_cols "Image" <img src="{{ session.userinfo.picture }}"> %}
```

However, this gives me `Could not parse the remainder: '<img' from '<img'`

I know I could modify the inclusion_tag function with some additional arguments that could provide the info but was hoping to keep that nice and generic.

It would be helpful if someone can either tell me whether what I'm doing is not possible or if there is a clean/non-hacky way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use string concatenation:

```
<table>
{% with "<img src='"|add:session.userinfo.picture|add:"'>" as image%}
{% row_with_cols "Image" image|safe %}
{% endwith %}
</table>
```

If you don't want to use endwith line, you should write to simple_tag for concatenation like :

```
@register.simple_tag()
def concat_str(*str_list):
    concat = ""
    for str in str_list:
        concat = concat + str
    return concat
```

and use of it

```
<table>
{% concat_str "<img src='" session.userinfo.picture "'>" as image %}
{% row_with_cols "Image" image|safe %}
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't crash at least, however `{{ session.userinfo.picture }}` is a string rather than a variable. Any ideas on how I can get it to treat it as a variable still?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Magic. However, it looks like I was worried it might :w. Thank you for getting it to work though. I've only been using Django for 2 weeks so finding out what is and isn't reasonable to do is seriously helpful.